# How to assign libname and resolve ERROR: Libname XXXX is not assigned?

Tags: sas

I have created a libname **XXXX** and have saved a table **Event_History_Main** in it, using:

```
libname XXXX meta library="XXXX" metaout=data;

data XXXX.Event_History_Main;
    set work.Event_History_Main;
run;
```

But when I try to run this code

```
data Event_History;
    set XXXX.Event_History_MAIN;
run;
```

I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Libname XXXX is not assigned.
```

**How to resolve it? What I missed out before above proc ?**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using RSUBMIT and ENDRSUBMIT? If yes, in which part of code?
If you have RSUBMIT and ENDRSUBMIT when you declared the libname, you must to write the seconde code in between RSUBMIT and ENDRSUBMIT.

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about. But no I am not using RSUBMIT ENDRSUBMIT... just the above codes, what I am using, nothing more. Thanks.

Comment: Then, have you an error like "ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement." when you run "libname XXXX meta library="XXXX" metaout=data;".

Comment: no. i did not get any error there. and the saved data table appears in xxxx